# How to repeat Complete gridview on single page using C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web, repeater

I am facing a problem when bind gridview.Actually i have a gridview on my Asp Webpage. And want to bind it multiple times. like this..

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
   {
   SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select *from Employee_table where Emp_Persent='"+i+"'",con); //
   SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds=new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
   GridView1.DataSource=ds;
   GridView1.DataBind();
   }
```

So when the gridview bind then it should be repeat Vertically on same page on every loop. And show the every Gridview data on same page..
So please help me in this problem..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lose the loop. The GridView will "repeat", by default, every record coming back from the DB.

You do not want to fill your page with separate GridViews for performance reasons, including the ViewState growing out of control.

I would also recommend using parameterized queries to avoid possible SQL Injection attacks:

[How to Fix SQL Injection Using Microsoft .Net Parameterized Queries](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries)

```
// Data layer method
public static DataSet GetProductsByOccasion(int empPercent)
{
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];

    parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@Emp_Persent", 
        System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 8, "empPercent");
    parameters[0].Value = empPercent;

    using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            return (SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(dbConnection, 
                CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    "GetEmployeesByPercent", parameters));
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```